# How to serve data for making static amp pages sharing same design?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

*For my understanding, using amplist, ampcarousel, ampimg needs an src which is always hard coded (depending upon product's detail page URL)*

For Eg. - https://www.example.com/amp/details/Samsung-smartphone-s5 
- https://www.example.com/amp/details/one-plus-3t
- https://www.example.com/amp/details/iphone-6s etc

As they all are details page but have different content like – title, price, images, list_items etc. so how you are providing these static data before making of final HTML?

Note: **On detail's page, the route path changes but the design remains same.**

**So where should I bring these data as making of thousands of similar pages, and manually writing AMP-HTML for all of them sounds redundant?**

Answer (score 0):

You may check this tutorial on how to [generate static AMP pages](http://pauldambra.github.io/2017/generating-static-amp.html). The basic idea is adapted from a [Jekyll plugin on github](https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll/). All styles are included in the head in the `<style amp-custom/>` element. It was found to be easier to just load all styles that way *even on non-AMP pages*. There was no measurable difference in page rendering with styles in a linked stylesheet versus in a style tag in the head.